# Getting one over on the boss

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

In my job as a poet for a national newspaper I am rarely faced with ethical decisions.  However, today was quite a challenge…

The editor came to me this morning and said, “Hey, I’ve heard about this website – they call it the *Puzzling Stock Exchange* or something…”

“*Stack* Exchange,” I corrected him, a little too quickly.  He narrowed his eyes a little.

“So you know it?”

I did my best to backtrack.  “Only very slightly – pretty sure I’ve heard of it somewhere… maybe just overheard someone… on the bus…”  My voice tailed off.

“Right,” continued the editor.  “Well, it seems this Puzzling Haystack Exchange is a website where people with nothing better to do go and create puzzles for other people to solve.  I mean, is that crazy or what?  Who *are* these people?  Why do they *do* this?!”

He guffawed heartily.  I glanced all around and forced out a laugh.  “Ha, yeah – who *are* they…?  I don’t know, that’s for sure…”  I closed my laptop shut so he couldn’t see the screen.

“Right!  So here’s the thing.”  He scooched right up next to me, so close I could smell his breath.  “I want today’s poem to be about this website, about what a terrible idea it is, how it’s a complete waste of time.  I need it by 5pm, okay?”  With that he left my office.

With a gulp, I re-opened my laptop.  The PSE Questions page was still open in my browser.  How was I going to do this??  I needed this job – it pays me well – but could I really sell out something I genuinely loved?!  I mulled this over for more than half of the time I had been allotted to write the poem…

Then it hit me.  I finally knew what I had to write – something which *appeared* to criticise the site, like my editor wanted, but which at the same time actually served to put across my own opinions about it too.

This is what I wrote:

> Puzzles are stupid and pointless!
>   So don’t con yourself that
>   They’re good for your brain
>   Scientists say
>   They serve no real purpose
>   It’s flawed logic to argue that
>   The opposite is true
>   Let nobody tell you
>   “Solving obscure and difficult puzzles is just good fun!”
>   What is the point of it all?
>   Any other activity
>   Is more enjoyable than
>   Spending one’s time thinking up brainteasers and cracking other people’s codes
>   Those riddles and connecting walls
>   Those anagrams and cryptic clues
>   Oh, how I delight in
>   Pouring down scorn on these
>   There are many who think their time is well spent
>   Decrypting ciphers, spotting patterns or thinking laterally
>   I, for one, enjoy spending my waking hours
>   Doing other things
>   I have no desire to be
>   Part of this puzzling community
>   I feel
>   It has no real purpose
>   So stop harping on about how
>   It’s inspiring to see what other users create
>   PSE is a drain on productivity
>   Don’t jump to the conclusion that
>   Contributing to this website brings great benefits

My editor was delighted and put it straight in to the day’s edition without looking harder at it.  Perhaps you can spot what I managed to smuggle past him?

**Given that this is the poem I submitted, how have I managed to express my own thoughts and views on PSE?**

<sub>**Post-script:** Now that this puzzle has been solved, I can gladly declare that although the poem is a Stiv original, the concept was actually inspired by two other poems I came across online: [*Refugees*](https://brianbilston.com/2016/03/23/refugees/) by Brian Bilston, and (the poem which initially inspired that one) [*The Lost Generation*](https://genius.com/Jonathan-reed-the-lost-generation-annotated) by Jonathan Reed. I find both of these not just impressive for their structure but very powerful in their messages - they're worth a read!</sub>

Comment: It's a clever piece of prose, but this sucks as poetry :-(

Comment: @Strawberry It's poetic justice :P

Comment: Are you familiar with rot13("Töqry, Rfpure, Onpu" ol Qbhtynf Ubsfgnqgre)?  There's a section in there with a very similar format...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman No, I'm not - worth a look?

Comment: Yeah, there's some pretty wild stuff in there.  In particular, there's a section I think called "Crab Canon" (based on a musical form J.S. Bach played around with which applies the same concept to sheet music) which reads very much like this, though it's written more like a stage-play rather than a poem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've expressed your views by

> making a poem that can be read backwards, line-by-line, to create a positive message rather than a negative one.
>
>  "Contributing to this website brings great benefits. Don’t jump to the conclusion that PSE is a drain on productivity. It’s inspiring to see what other users create, so stop harping on about how it has no real purpose. [...] "

(And as prompted in the comments: your real views are...)

> ...*quite the reverse* of what the poem says.

Comment: BOOM! Exactly right. Are you able to give a pithy 2/3 word phrase to sum it up in the sense of "Although this is what the poem says my own views are...WORD-WORD-WORD"? Quick work!

Comment: @Stiv Is this the phrase you're looking for?

Comment: Beautiful! Just adds a little flourish :) The green checkmark is yours... +1 too